# Open map that is not continuous

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I was trying to find an open map that is not continuous, here was my effort, is it ok?

Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$ where $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard topology and $\mathbb{Z}$ has the discrete topology. Then $\{1\}$ is open in $\mathbb{Z}$. However $f^{-1}(\{1\})=[1,2)$, which is not open in $\mathbb{R}$, so $f$ is not continuous. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ has the discrete topology, the image of any open set is necessarily open. Thus, $f$ is an open map.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: You can also have much nastier functions. For example the Conway base 13 function is open (maps any nonempty open set to all of the real line) and is discontinuous everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that example is fine. In fact the identity from $(X, \tau)$ ( a non-discrete space) to $X$ in the discrete topology is always open and non-continuous.